# Scaling view around arbitrary point

Tags: android, zooming

How can I perform scaling around fixed(focus) point? i.e. focus should stay on the same position while I'm scaling.I use following code:

```
   public void scaleAroundPoint(float scale,float focusX,float focusY) {
     float oldX=focusX/this.getScaleX();
     float oldY=focusY/this.getScaleY();
     float oldScale=this.getScaleX();
     this.setScaleX(scale);
     this.setScaleY(scale);
     float newX=focusX/this.getScaleX();
     float newY=focusY/this.getScaleY();
     float dx=oldX-newX;
     float dy=oldY-newY;
     this.setX(this.getX()-dx);
     this.setY(this.getY()-dy);
}
```

But it results in focus is not the point I pass in focusX,focusY

PS:
The setPivotX,setPivotY methods are not suitable for me,since I'm also performing 2-axis scrolling simultaniously with zooming so its preferable the pivot point stays in 0,0

Comment: yes `View#setPivot*` methods are for stuff like that, what view do you want to translate / scale?

Comment: Its my custom view based on FrameLayout.I tried to play with setPivot methods but it behaves unusual.For instance:
My view has 0,0 coordinates.I set pivot point to 100,100.My view jumps so its top left corner now on -100,-100.After that if I scale view to some value and set  pivot point back to 0,0 - my view's top left corner goes back where it was before, but scaling corrups(view stays scaled but NOT relative 100,100, but relative 0,0)

Comment: ok, do you have to use `View#set*` methods? cannot you just translate / scale the content when drawing it on the `Canvas`?

Comment: Well I'll try if wouldn't find another solutions.Canvas painting has huge disadvantage: when I do canvas.scale - it doesn't affect view's width/height.

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/ma8q6YYr), detectors are here: https://github.com/pskink/android-gesture-detectors

Comment: yeah, thanks.I know how to handle gestures.The problem is how to transform view after I got gesture event.

Comment: You have all in `FL#update` method, but actually it is much more better to use `Matrix` for view drawing and not using `View#set*` methods for scaling / translating / pivot

Comment: @pskink.Thanks for an example.
BTW:Why is there no this.setOnTouchListener(this); or something like this and shouldn't FL implements OnTouchListener interface?

Comment: sorry didn't see your example first

Comment: because it is `public boolean View#onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` which is called with every `MotionEvent`, note: it is `onTouchEvent`, and not `onTouch`

Comment: ok,thanks.Will try it hour or two

Comment: stiill doesn't work.I managed to compile it but onTouchEvent never get called.Here is my class:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68778662/BidirectionalScrollView.java

Comment: whats the stack trace? did my class work?

Comment: oh sorry.There was filter in the debug panel.Yes its get called.But my view isn't moving when i drag it

Comment: you mean `content`? it is not set

Comment: nope content is set and I see it.Looks like update function is not reachable from the scope of MoveGestureDetector.OnMoveGestureListener.Will try to pass this pointer there

Comment: you are calling `content.setPivotX(0);` but there is nowhere `content = ...`, see your [code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68778662/BidirectionalScrollView.java) and press `^Fcontent`, deos my class work? does it scale / translate?

Comment: content is created by layout inflater and I attach my views to it. here is part of the layout:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68778662/game_fragment.xml

Comment: if it does not work, just for testing, set it to some `ImageView` like i did and you will be 100% sure it is attached to your `FrameLayout`

Comment: It even doesn't call onMove

Comment: ok , did my `FL` class work? did you try it? why dont you copy my exact code? just use `SimpleOnMoveGestureListener` , not `OnMoveGestureListener`

Comment: let me try with new project

Comment: why new project? just use `SimpleOnMoveGestureListener` (and not `OnMoveGestureListener`) or return `true` from `onMoveBegin`

Comment: yeah in new project your code works well with imageView.Will try to change it to FrameLayout

Comment: and now remove everything from `update` method and add this code: `@Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.concat(m);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void update() {
        invalidate();
    }`, no need for those: `setPivot*` / `setScale*` / `setTranslation*`

Comment: done.Nothing changed.So what why is preferable?

Comment: overriding dispatchDraw is much easier

Comment: Thanks dude.Your code really saved me.I've been fighting for already several days with this piece of code.

Comment: is there way how I can award you?